# Catch all emails and save them in MySQL

Tags: email, mysql, smtp

I want to do something like Facebook has with it message system.
When you reply to email sent from Facebook User, it automatically gets in his message box.
This is done, because you reply to {longidofmsg}@facebook.com, according to {longidofmsg} FB find route to user and it's message box.

**Can you suggest simple out of the box solution: Which will catch all emails, checks if they have correct {longidofmsg} and saves them to mysql?**

I've found something like this:
https://github.com/deitch/smtp-tester/ , but it needs a lot of hacking

Comment: I believe this was covered pretty well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814678/best-way-to-store-mail-in-db-postfix

Comment: @Tim Thank you fro reference. Please consider that I'm not looking for POP3,IMAP,etc. Just bare SMTP->MySQL. Installing and maintaining Postfix is overkill for me.

Comment: Probably not. Mail servers aren't simple. Especially ones that do routing and storage via SQL databases.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is this product, it's open source and it's called [dbmail](http://www.dbmail.org/).

Based on it's description it sounds like exactly what you want:

> DBMail is an open-source project that enables storage of mail messages
>   in a relational database. Currently MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and
>   SQLite can be used as storage backends.